# error when importing gz files into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran into an error when importing gzipped tab delimited files into bigquery

The output I got was:

```
root@a20c6fbdf9b5:/opt/batch/jobs# bq show -j bqjob_r5720e2f2267a5a5b_0000014d09571f27_1
Job infra-bedrock-861:bqjob_r5720e2f2267a5a5b_0000014d09571f27_1

  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- -----------------
  load       FAILURE   30 Apr 08:00:44   0:02:05

Errors encountered during job execution. Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with: <H:|\ufc0f\ufffd(>
Failure details:
 - File: 1 / Line:1 / Field:1: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered:
   field starts with: <\ufff>
 - File: 1 / Line:3 / Field:1: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered:
   field starts with: <\u0475\ufffd=\ufffd\ufffd\u03d6>
 - File: 1 / Line:4 / Field:1: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered:
   field starts with: <-\ufffd\ufffdY\u049a\ufffd>
 - File: 1 / Line:6 / Field:1: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered:
   field starts with: <\u018e\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd>
```

I tried manually downloading the files, unzipping and then uploading the files again. The uncompressed files could be imported into bigquery without any problems.

This looks like a bug in bigquery with zip files

Comment: zip or gzip? BigQuery consumes gzip, not zip

Comment: sorry for inconsistent formulation, but as the title hints it was gzip files with extension .gz and not zip files

Comment: can you share a sample file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the job configuration, you include a non-gzip file as the first uri, ending in  `.../20150426/_SUCCESS`. BigQuery uses the first file to determine whether compression is enabled.

Assuming this file is empty, you can remove it from your load requests to fix this. If there is data in this file, attach a ".gz" suffix or re-order this file so it is not first in the uri list.

Comment: Thanks, excluding that file from the set of files to be imported fixed the problem